# Execute vim commands from a script

Tags: vim, shell-script

SO I've created a script that opens all of the files in a particular directory in vim in separate terminal tabs for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.14;


my $wd = '/home/luke/Pokemon-Battle-Simulator';
chdir($wd);

opendir(DIR,$wd);
my @files = readdir(DIR);

my $cmd = 'gnome-terminal';
my $tab = ' --tab-with-profile=def';
for my $file(@files)
{
    if (($file  ne ".") and ($file ne ".."))
    {
        my $title = '--title=' . $file;
        my $e = "-e 'vim " . $file . "'";
        $cmd .= join(' ', $tab, $title, $e); 
    }
}
print $cmd;

`$cmd`
```

However, I am frequently needing to transfer these files between my linux box and a windows box, where I'm editing with notepad++.

When I import them to linux/vim The formatting is a bit off, so I have to explicitly declare to the vim file `:source ~/.vimrc`

I would like to have my script execute this for me when opening the files, but I am not sure how to go about it.

So, how can I pass a vim command to vim using an external program?

**EDIT:** The script above generates a list of strings(not a literal list, its still one big string) of the form:

```
gnome-terminal .....  --tab-with-profile=def --title=BattleOps.py -e 'vim BattleOps.py'......
```

Comment: I answered how to execute an arbitrary vim command after file is opened, but actually file `~/.vimrc` should be sourced automatically anyway. Are you sure it isn't sourced?

Comment: all i am sure of is that typing :source ~/.vimrc fixes my problem and that a simple "gg=G" does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give `-c` option to vim to execute commands after the first file has been read, like this: (modified line from your script)

```
my $e = "-e 'vim -c \"source /path/to/my/file\" " . $file . "'";
```

Read about it:

```
:help -c
```